# How can we calculate weighted cumulative sum of squares with prefix range updates by one?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, segment-tree, binary-indexed-tree

Given an array `A` with `n` elements which starts with all `0`s and another array `W` also with n elements (all greater than `0`), we want to perform the following operation repeatedly;

For a given k, increment `A[0], A[1], .... A[k]` each by 1, and report the value of `A[0]^2 * W[0] + A[1]^2 * W[1] + ... + A[n-1]^2 * W[n-1]`.

Looking for an `O(log n)` solution (per query), or faster.

Comment: Yes, the ... was missing. Fixed that.

Comment: Do we have any common values in each array or just a random numbers?

Comment: W is random numbers, positive floats. The way A is setup it will be non increasing.

Comment: seriously u find log (n) solution? where u need n operation to take w array. do u want to do it o(n) ? i think u want faster than n*logn

Comment: log(n) per query @GolamMazidsajib